# WPF Listview, align listview item horizontal dynamic not in xaml

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How can i dynamic align the listview items in a listview.

-- NOT IN XAML --

```
lv.View = GridView

GridView.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "CrewId", .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("CrewId")})
GridView.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "FirstName", .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("FirstName")})
GridView.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "LastName", .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("LastName")})
GridView.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "Country", .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("Country")})
GridView.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "Rank", .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("Rank")})

Try
    lv.ItemsSource = dsCrew.Tables(0).DefaultView
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?

Comment: The text in column 1 of the listview must be placed to the right.

Comment: Dont manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to align all of the `ListViewItem`s:

```
lv.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Ahh, that's why this solution didn't work... you have more than one column. Of course I couldn't tell that before you showed your code. Ok, I found a way to align all of the columns to the right... I understand that this is not exactly what you're after, but I'll add this here until I find a better solution:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, 
    HorizontalAlignment.Right));
YourListView.ItemContainerStyle = style;
```

You may be able to work out the rest in the meantime.

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

OK, so I've had a good search online and this is the closest that I've come to an answer for you... there is an article called [How to center and right align text inside a GridViewColumn in a WPF ListView Control](http://tsells.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/how-to-center-and-right-align-text-inside-a-gridviewcolumn-in-a-wpf-listview-control/) on Tracy Sells' website which shows how to do this in XAML... yes, I know you wanted it in code, but you'll have to do some of the work here:

```
<ListView 
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <TextBlock Text="MyText" TextAlignment="Center" />   
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    <ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

We can adapt my second bit of code to implement the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, 
    HorizontalAlignment.Stretch));
YourListView.ItemContainerStyle = style;
```

That's as far as I can go unfortunately, as I've never actually used a `ListView`. So now, you just need to find out how to set the `TextAlignment` on the content of the relevant `GridViewColumn`. I noticed that there is not much help with doing this kind of stuff in code and that is simply because this is *not* the usual way of doing it. Either way, good luck with finding out how to accomplish the last part of the puzzle.

Comment: I have try that but this won't work and i want only column 1 the the right.

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond to that as I just tried it and it did work. Maybe if you actually showed all of your relevant code then we could help further?

Comment: 'code'GridView.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "CrewId", .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("CrewId")})
GridView.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "FirstName", .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("FirstName")})
GridView.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "LastName", .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("LastName")})
GridView.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "Country", .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("Country")})

Try
   lv.ItemsSource = dsCrew.Tables(0).DefaultView
catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try

Comment: @LudiKuyper, please can you add the code into your question so that it is easy to see and then delete your comment?

Comment: It is indeed, thanks. Can you please delete the comment with the code in now as well? I updated my answer with an intermediate solution.

Comment: What do you use instead of a listview. My problem is that must show several columns with data of a sqldatabase. The user must be able to sort every row and isn't alowed to edit the data.

Comment: Personally, I never use any 'grid' displays as I design my own UI controls, but for most people, the [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) is the control of choice... it's much easier to work with.